# why my code for edge function for week 4 in cs50 course is not working?

Tags: c, cs50

please check the problem deatils [here](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/4/filter/more/). please find the last function to implement i.e edge detection function. the belwo code is not working properly and only detecting the edge for first pixel.

```
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    //creating a copy of image
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];

    //copying original image to copy
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }
    //Initializing value of x & y kernels

    int Gx[3][3] = {{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};
    int Gy[3][3] = {{-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}};

    //itirating over height and width

    int sxr, sxb, sxg, syr, syb, syg;
    sxr = sxb = sxg = syr = syb = syg = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
                {
                    //skips if the pixel is outside the boundary
                    if(i + k - 1 < 0 || i + k - 1 > height || j + l - 1 < 0 || j + l - 1 > width)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // if the pixel is inside the boundary
                    sxr += ((copy[i - 1 + k][j -  1 + l].rgbtRed) * (Gx[k][l]));
                    sxb += ((copy[i - 1 + k][j -  1 + l].rgbtBlue) * (Gx[k][l]));
                    sxg += ((copy[i - 1 + k][j -  1 + l].rgbtGreen) * (Gx[k][l]));

                    syr += ((copy[i - 1 + k][j -  1 + l].rgbtRed) * (Gy[k][l]));
                    syb += ((copy[i - 1 + k][j -  1 + l].rgbtBlue) * (Gy[k][l]));
                    syg += ((copy[i - 1 + k][j -  1 + l].rgbtGreen) * (Gy[k][l]));

                }
            }
            int srtR = round(sqrt(sxr * sxr + syr * syr));
            int srtB = round(sqrt(sxb * sxb + syb * syb));
            int srtG = round(sqrt(sxg * sxg + syg * syg));

            //corner case of RGB values > 255
            if (srtR > 255)
            {
                srtR = 255;
            }
            if (srtB > 255)
            {
                srtB = 255;
            }
            if (srtG > 255)
            {
                srtG = 255;
            }
            copy[i][j].rgbtRed =  srtR;
            copy[i][j].rgbtBlue = srtB;
            copy[i][j].rgbtGreen = srtG;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = copy[i][j].rgbtRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = copy[i][j].rgbtBlue;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = copy[i][j].rgbtGreen;

        }
    }
}
```

in This code the check50 is [this](https://submit.cs50.io/check50/277bbd43a0f75bc2156f9eea6f6c25be09d0491b)

Further i found out that the below code works

```
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    //creating a copy of image
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];

    //copying original image to copy
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }
    //Initializing value of x & y kernels

    int Gx[3][3] = {{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};
    int Gy[3][3] = {{-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}};

    //itirating over height and width



    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            float sxr, sxb, sxg, syr, syb, syg;
            sxr = sxb = sxg = syr = syb = syg = 0;

            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++)
                {
                    //skips if the pixel is outside the boundary
                    if(i + k - 1 < 0 || i + k - 1 >= height || j + l - 1 < 0 || j + l - 1 >= width)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // if the pixel is inside the boundary
                    sxr += ((copy[i - 1 + k][j -  1 + l].rgbtRed) * (Gx[k][l]));
                    sxb += ((copy[i - 1 + k][j -  1 + l].rgbtBlue) * (Gx[k][l]));
                    sxg += ((copy[i - 1 + k][j -  1 + l].rgbtGreen) * (Gx[k][l]));

                    syr += ((copy[i - 1 + k][j -  1 + l].rgbtRed) * (Gy[k][l]));
                    syb += ((copy[i - 1 + k][j -  1 + l].rgbtBlue) * (Gy[k][l]));
                    syg += ((copy[i - 1 + k][j -  1 + l].rgbtGreen) * (Gy[k][l]));

                }
            }
            int srtR = round(sqrt((sxr * sxr) + (syr * syr)));
            int srtB = round(sqrt(sxb * sxb + syb * syb));
            int srtG = round(sqrt(sxg * sxg + syg * syg));

            //corner case of RGB values > 255
            if (srtR > 255)
            {
                srtR = 255;
            }
            if (srtB > 255)
            {
                srtB = 255;
            }
            if (srtG > 255)
            {
                srtG = 255;
            }
            image[i][j].rgbtRed =  srtR;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = srtB;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = srtG;
        }
    }


}
```

In the above code only the declaration of variable diference is there.

Can someone explain why  the place of declaring variables have such impact in code as above

Comment: The problem description you linked to uses a horrific color combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone explain why the place of declaring variables have such impact in code as above

Well, in your case, the working code declares *and initialises* `sxr`, `sxb`, `sxg`, `syr`, `syb` and `syg` inside the scope of the `for( int j ...` loop. Your non working code declares and initialises them only once at the beginning. This means that the working code resets them for every `i` and `j` (every pixel?) but the non working code accumulates the values over the whole image.

Comment: Huge Help. now i know. the variables needs to be reset at every itiration of j but as i declared at the begining of loop it accumulated. thats why all other values other than first values were maxed out. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Initializing a new variable inside the loop at each iteration completely changes the actual computations that are performed, for example:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    i++;
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

Will output numbers from 1 to 10, while the code:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    int i = 0;        // this `i` shadows the outer `i`
    i++;
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

Will output the number 1 infinitely, because `i` is initialized to zero on each iteration. `i++` (and `printf`) refers to the `i` declared inside the loop, while the `while` condition refers the `i` declared outside the loop. This is called *shadowing*.

> the below code is not working properly and only detecting the edge for first pixel.

Exactly, because you are initializing a new variable with the coordinates to 0 at the start each iteration.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo `refers to the i declared inside the loop, while the while condition refers the i declared outside the loop. This is called shadowing` are you sure about this? I think the variable `i` in the condition is the same that is modified in the loop

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. Also, variables declared inside the block are not available in the `while` condition. You can also show it clearly [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/zrd3167K7) which makes it loop 10 times because I added `i++` _before_ the declaration of the new `i`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks a lot, I program a lot in Python but I am beginner in C, so I have many such doubts

Comment: i think the code is not working as it in not resetting at every loop as answered by some one in this thread.  more info?

Comment: @Nikhil True. The reason if because of the shadowing that was mentioned in this answer. I missed the two occurances of "resetting" when I edited it previously.

Answer (score 0):

"Can someone explain why the place of declaring variables have such impact in code as above"

Because integer arithmetic is very different than floating point arithmetic.

`int x = 7 / 2` assigns x the value of 3, while `float x = 7.0 / 2.0` assigns `3.5`.  Using `int` instead `float` leads to a loss of precision.

In your case, the code:

```
int srtR = round(sqrt(sxr * sxr + syr * syr));
```

Is simply discarding the non-integer portion of the value returned by `round`.  If `round` returns 2.34, that line of code assigns the value of `2` to `srtR`.